# Passing formdata from Phonegap to PHP with JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, cordova

I am developing an app in phonegap, and I am trying to pass formdata from phonegap to a remote server with jquery and json and save it to the mysql database.
I have never used json before, and I am really uncertain of how to recieve and parse this data on the server.

Could anyone help me write a simple php script to handle this?

This is the form and jquery I am using to send data:

```
<form method="post" id="infoForm">
       <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="" placeholder="First Name"  />
       <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" value="" placeholder="Last Name"  />   
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email"  />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>

$('#infoForm').submit(function() {

    var postTo = 'http://siteurl.com';

    $.post(postTo,({first_name: $('[name=first_name]').val(), last_name: $('[name=last_name]').val(), email: $('[name=email]').val()}),
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
        if(data != "") {
            // do something
        } else {
            // couldn't connect
        }        
        },'json');
    return false;
});
```

I have been trying to find a solution for hours without any result.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can avoid structure like this:

```
{first_name: $('[name=first_name]').val(), last_name: $('[name=last_name]').val(), email: $('[name=email]').val()}
```

With jQuery's built in serialize method:

```
$.serialize(this)
```

As far as you already specified "json" as a response type "data" variable will contain already unserialized JSON object.

In php script side of things you need to do following:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
exit();
```

Of course you need to change $_POST superglobal with your array/object of result, I used it for demo purpose in script line above.

Obviously $_POST variable contains data passed from Ajax request, such variable is available in any scope in PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is that you send the data in a GET or POST request to your server (http://siteurl.com/index.php for example).  Then on the server (index.php) you look at the $_GET, $_POST, or $_REQUEST variables to find that data that you sent.  Once you have the data you can you json_decode to easily format the data for you.  json_decode will take your JSON string and convert it in to a php variable for you.

Here is a quick tutorial explaining how you can perform this using PHP:
http://webhole.net/2009/08/31/how-to-read-json-data-with-php/

json_decode:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

$_REQUEST:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php