# Moving php apps to Android and iPhone

Tags: php, android, iphone, cordova, sencha-touch

I am a php developer with a few web apps like a project management app and a forum i'd like to  move to Android and iPhone.

I've heard of developers using Sencha Touch and PhoneGap to develop native apps and I know they support HTML5, CSS and Javascript, but how abot PHP?  And is are there any other APIs/frameworks I should consider that better support local server scripting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking about webapp, maybe you can avoid building an app by having a mobile enabled version of your website compliant with all the client browsers.

Have a look at jquerymobile, it is compliant with mostly all the mobile browsers and you will be able to reuse your code.

To answer correctly, you can call your webservices using ajax to fetch json/xml/etc data from Phonegap because it is using jQuerymobile ;-)

Have a look at this discussion here on Stackoverflow :

[Passing formdata from Phonegap to PHP with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170994/passing-formdata-from-phonegap-to-php-with-json)

Hope this helps

Comment: The PM app is based off an individual user's input and doesn't need to be updated so the php files can be in a local database.  Thanks, I'll look into PhoneGap and jQuerymobile.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side scripting language and your .php files have to be stored on the server side. You can access them asynchronously with Ajax, so no, you can not include php files (with reasonable time and effort) in your app.

Answer (score -2):

The only smart way to go here is native iOS apps, forget PHP, Android and the rest of that crap.   By the way I'm not trying to be an iOS snob here but am just reflecting on a few realities.   One is that iOS apps can actually make money though a web replacement app might not.  The second issue is that going native demands a reboot on your part, that is best done on one platform until you get up to speed.  The third issue is that users now a days expect well performing apps that don't have a lot of web cruft in them.  Fourth the Android marketplace is screwed, you are far more likely to establish that critical user base on iOS as you can target a handful of platforms running the latest generation of iOS, android is by comparison a pathetic mess of old versions of android running on all sorts of hardware.

On iOS look a BlueAlien as an example of a better than web method of accessing Reddit.

Comment: I don't really have a preference at this point, I'm more looking for the right framework that will allow me to quickly get my php apps to both markets.  From what I found, Sencha Touch and PhoneGap are the best alternatives for this situation.  I could also develop for iOS and port to Android with Mono but it's not economically logical and I don't feel like getting into Objective C since I work mostly in OOP.